# Autocomplete environment variable with shift held

Tags: ubuntu, bash, autocomplete

I'm using Ubuntu bash, and when I try to autocomplete an environment variable while holding shift, the variable does not expand. Instead, I have to release the shift key. Is there any way to allow the expansion to occur while holding shift?

```
> cd $HOM  # desired: TAB+SHIFT to get $HOME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following line to your `~/.inputrc` file:

```
"\e[Z": complete
```

For the details of why you need to do this see this question: [.inputrc TAB not behaving as expected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17012/inputrc-tab-not-behaving-as-expected) and the available [bash readline commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17012/inputrc-tab-not-behaving-as-expected).